# Unable to use https on Amazon loadbalancer

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, ssl-certificate, https

I have a wild card certificate for a domain and have configured it on a load balancer. The load balancer has an EC2 instance assigned. I am using the domain name to point to the load balancer through Amazon Route53.

[image: Load Balancer configuration screen shot]

The http call ex: http://test.example.com is working fine.

But When I use https://test.example.com the browser takes a long time and then gives the message "This webpage is not available".

The Cipher used for https is "ELBSecurityPolicy-2014-01"

For testing pourpose I took an AMI from another account where https was working for that domain and tried here. Even that gave the same problem.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if 443 port is open to the world or not. Trying using telnet

```
telnet <host> 443
```

See if that work ? If not. Check the security settings of the load balancer instance.

Comment: Now I get a SSL error saying "You attempted to reach test.example.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.example.com. 
This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. 
An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of test.example.com." Since it is related, I posted this in the same thread.

Comment: Yes. That definitely is a problem with your https configuration or they way you have setup your https certificate etc.

Comment: Thanks again. Fixed it. I had used level1.level2.example.com. changed it to level1.example as the certificate I have is for level1.example.com